# Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Observable<IProduct[]>'

Tags: angular

I am new to typescript, and I get this error

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'IProduct[]'.
>     Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Observable'.

My service class is :

```
getProducts() : Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this._http.get<IProduct[]>(this._productUrl)
    .do(data=>console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
    .catch(this.handleError);
}


private handleError(err : HttpErrorResponse){
    console.log(err.message);
    return Observable.throw(err.message)
}
```

Where is it wrong and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: show the _http.get function. Seems like it returns a value of observable instead of observable.

Comment: How does your receiving component code look like?

Comment: Use function binding in cases like above because it allows the function to be called with clearer context. Though, current code will also work fine but using bind is a good practice. https://thenewstack.io/mastering-javascript-callbacks-bind-apply-call/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If this question comes from the Angular course on Pluralsight by @DeborahKurata, the answer is in the next module, "Subscribing to an Observable".

In the `ngOnInit(): void` method in product-list.component.ts, change this

```
    this.products = this._productService.getProducts();
    this.filteredProducts = this.products;
```

to

```
    this._productService.getProducts()
        .subscribe(products => { 
            this.products = products; 
            this.filteredProducts = this.products; 
        }, error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `http.get<IProduct[]>(this._productUrl)` returns an array of `IProduct` and your code tries to return it as an *observable* `IProduct` array. To return an observable array from your `getProducts` function (using RxJS), you could do this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

return observable.of(this._http.get<IProduct[]>(this._productUrl));
```

Comment: this.http.get itself returns an Observable, thus, there is no need to explicitly wrap it in a Observable.

Answer (score 0):

In case you also come from pluralsight - Angular Component Communication.

After you perform the change from K0D4 answer.

At the product.service.ts replace the ErrorObservable with throwError:

```
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs/';
```

Then at the bottom, the handleError does not return ErrorObservable, you can use throwError:

```
private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    ....
    return throwError(errorMessage);
}
```

I started getting the Observer errors after updating to Angular 7, and it was because of this.