# Type 'Observable<{} | IProduct[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<IProduct[]>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular6

**Currently going through the [Deborah Kurata course on Angular 6](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-getting-started-update/table-of-contents)**

I've done with the Observables module, but running into the follow error in my `products.service`.

[image]

I found [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914878/property-includes-is-missing-in-type-observableiproduct), but I've already done that and don't believe that was actually for the problem experienced here.

I also found this issue here about it, but the fix did not work:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20349

The fix was suppose to just be `return Rx.Observable.of` but there is no `of` on `Observable`.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

// Interfaces
import { IProduct } from './product';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {
  private productUrl = 'api/products/products.json';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productUrl).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
    );
  }
}
```

---

I found that if I just change the type of Observable returned to  the code passes, but I feel it's a cheat and I lose the benefit of `Typescript`:

```
getProducts(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productUrl).pipe(
    tap(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `.pipe` in the first place.

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera ah, ok so yeah the problem goes away when I remove the pipe, however `.tap` and `.catchError` are important methods and don't mutate the data returned from the get request, so how can this be resolved another way?

Comment: What happens if you replace `tap` with `map`?

Comment: @camden_kid same error after replacing with `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically hover over `.pipe` to check it's return value.

`.tap` just returns what it gets. But I think, `catchError` might return an `Object`. That's why it's return type is assumed as `Observable<{}|IProduct[]>`.

**Fix 1.** Use this in that case.

```
getProducts(): Observable<{}|IProduct[]> {
  return this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productUrl).pipe(
    tap(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

In the receiving component, you might want to do this:

```
products => { this.products = products as IProduct[] };
```

**Fix 2.** If you don't want to change your return type and then fix the code where you've subscribed to this observable, just get rid of the `catchError` here:

```
getProducts(): Observable <IProduct[] > {
  return this.http.get < IProduct[] > (this.productUrl).pipe(
    tap(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
  );
}
```

**Fix 3.** Or simply get rid of the `.pipe` in the first place. You're using `.tap` for logging anyway. So it's not adding any value to your code. As far as catching the error is concerned, you can do that either in an HttpInterceptor or at the place where you'll be `subscribing` to what this method is returning.

```
getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
  return this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productUrl);
}
```

Comment: Ah interesting, yes this works... but why I guess. Is it assuming that I may get back an empty object instead of the interface I specified? Curious...

Comment: Ah there is a problem here, now in the receiving component, `Type '{} | IProduct[]` is not assignable to type 'IProduct[]'. ==> `products => {
        this.products = products;`

Comment: Ok so looks like I am forced to remove the `pipe`, I do have an error message in the receiving component. Just unfortunate I can't use `pipe` for `tap` which could be helpful in a different kinda of app with more streaming type data.

Comment: I don't think `tap` is the culprit here. I think `catchError` is

Comment: Ah I had an error inside of my `handleError` method. I didn't import `throwError` from: `import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';` You have great answers too, but this is what was giving me a headache. + 1